# How to add new line in text file in output from remote shell script using plink

Tags: windows, text, newlines

From windows i am executing a remote shell script using putty plink

```
cmd>plink.exe -ssh username@hostipd -pw gbG8qs4 /user/alice/listoffiles.sh > C:\log1.txt
```

Shell script in remote server

```
#! /bin/bash

echo -e "Hellow\nWorld"
```

I am getting the output in log1.txt is HelloWorld without any newline. How to get ouput as

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Did you try \r\n as  newline ?

Comment: I hope that's not your real password here. If it is, change it now.

Comment: Gilles. I haven't written real password here

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a newline in the output. The problem is that this is a Unix newline, which Windows doesn't recognize. Unix encodes newlines as the LF (line feed) character, whereas Windows newlines consist of the two-character sequence CRLF (carriage return, line feed).

To view the output correctly under Windows, use just about anything other than the `type` command in `cmd` or the Notepad editor.

If you want to produce output with Windows newlines, you can pipe your script through `sed 's/$/\r/'`. But note that this output will not work normally under Linux: the extra CR character at the end of the line will be considered part of the line by many applications.